# Unit test for Serilog write to console

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, serilog, serilog-exceptions

Application is in .net framework and using Serilog for logging.

Configuration

```
Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger()
```

In Unit test how to verify that logger has the values which is expected to be?

Is there any way to read the values using any of Serilog api/methods?

Comment: are you seeking to validate that you configured it correctly, or that some app logic wrote the correct log info ?

Comment: Yes want to check if the configuration is proper
And the logs which I'm writing is as expected per the logic I put

Comment: I would say Serilog can be trusted - it has its own tests, and so can stdout - so, I would not be testing to validate such concerns. (You could run the exe, capture the oiutpiut and verify it includes a message, but again, the value wouldnt be clear to me)